# Trying to get property of non-object using laravel 5.3 (message.php)

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

[image]i am trying to get all messages that are sava in messages table in database but an error accured.

message.blade.php:

```
    <div class="sms">
<ul>
        @foreach($messages as $message)
            <li class="list-group-item"> {{$message->user->name}} : {{$message->message}}
                @if($message->user_id === Auth::user()->id)
                    <div class="action">
                        <a href="/delete/messages/{{$message->id}}">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                        /
                        <a href="/message/edit/{{$message->id}}">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                @endif
            </li>
        @endforeach
</ul>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function GetMessages(){
    $messages = Messages::all();
    return view('message')->with('messages',$messages);
}
```

MessagesModel:

```
    class Messages extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'messages';
    protected $fillable = ['message','user_id'];
    protected $timestamp=false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: possibly there is message without user )

Comment: which is your line 9?

Comment: line 9 -> @foreach()

Comment: Show you Messages model

Comment: @mcklayin i upload the model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You should always perform checks on relationships unless you are confident a user will always be assigned to a message.

```
{{ ($message->user) ? $message->user->name : 'No User' }}
```

Comment: It's a crutch ) we need to see Messages model to udnerstand what happend

Comment: Why do you need to see their model?  It could just be that one of the messages has no user_id in the database, not a hard concept..

Comment: You could be right, of course, but  according to code if no user, we need to remove\hide  <li>  by checking you codnition above

Comment: Likely not.  `$message->user_id === Auth::user()->id` will never evaluate to true if `$message->user_id` is null, since `Auth::user()->id` can usually never be null.